# Understanding how shared object file works .so

Tags: c, linux

I want to understand how `.so` works. Eventually I would like to make my own `malloc()`. But to get the infrastructure ready I just created a sample `malloc()` function and just printing inside it.

I compiled the following file (`my_malloc.c`):

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void* malloc(size_t sz)
{
    printf("malloc\n");
    return NULL;
}

void free(void *p)
{
    printf("free\n");
}
```

and created a `.so` using the following command:

```
 gcc -shared -fPIC -o my_malloc.so my_malloc.c
```

Now I created a `hello.c` file and I am using the `malloc()` function in this file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    malloc(64);
    return 0;
}
```

Then I've compiled this file with the following command:

```
gcc hello.c -o hello.o
```

I used `LD_PRELOAD` to override the standard `malloc()` implementation. When I run `hello.o` I get the segmentation fault:

```
LD_PRELOAD=./my_malloc.so ./hello.o
Segmentation fault
```

Why?

Comment: Add the command line you are using to compile `hello.o`.

Comment: gcc hello.c -o hello.o

Comment: Analyzing the core dump with `gdb` shows that you have an infinite recursion between `puts` and `malloc`, hence stack overflow. Standard library also uses `malloc()`, keep this in mind :)

Comment: @DanilaKiver could you tell how you debugged it using gdb? I was not able to run gdb and analyse the failure.

Comment: Run `hello` as you've specified in the question. After the crash the system will produce the core dump. Then run `coredumpctl debug hello` - it will find the last core dump from `hello` and open it with `gdb`. When you are in `gdb`, run `bt` - it will print you the stack trace with the recursion.

Comment: More to the point, `printf()` and [even `getchar()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57308691/10306503) will also use `malloc()`, and at least on Linux, they will not call it directly, but go through whatever `LD_PRELOAD` override.

Comment: *"I want to understand how .so works"* - You should read Drepper's [How To Write Shared Libraries](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/a/1/e/dsohowto.pdf).